# как сопоставить множество элементов из множества массивов в цикле

Tags: javascript

кажется, что ответ плавает где-то на поверхности, но уже битый час не могу сообразить...

в общем есть функция ajax, которая возвращает множество объектов(количество объектов всегда разное), в каждом из которых есть массив с элементами(количество элементов тоже всегда разное).

нужно в итоге отрисовать таблицу, в которой элементы будут сопоставлены друг другу.например, есть два объекта A(i,j,k), B(o,t,p), результат должен выглядеть так:

---

i   o

---

i   t

---

i   p

---

j   o

---

j   t

---

j   p

---

k   o

---

k   t

---

k   p

---

заранее благодарен

Comment: "функция ajax, которая возвращает множество ..." - вряд ли "функция ajax" возвращает то, что Вы думаете.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var A = { i: 1, j: 2, k: 3 };
var B = { o: 1, t: 2, p: 3 };

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

for (var i in A) {
  for (var j in B) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = A[i];
    tr.appendChild(td);
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = B[j];
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table id="myTable">

  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: какая в данном случае принципиальная разница между массивами и объектами?

Comment: @Grundy, к элементу массива легче обращаться (A[i])

Comment: в объекте то же самое `A[i]`

Comment: @Grundy, а можно пример кода?

Comment: Все то же самое только вместо `for`, использовать `for..in`

Comment: @Grundy, не знал, спасибо, поправил